# 19.04 - HP - System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults. + Rebooting instead of Shutting down

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, hp, 19.04

My laptop is an HP ProBook 4540s with Kubuntu.

Under 18.04 and 18.10, I did not have this issue.

In 19.04 I do. I tested this many times.

2 issues.
First one is, when booting, I get `System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.` screen. Sometimes it adds `Creating boot entry "Boot0001" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"` after it and in that case, the laptop does not boot for 2-3 more minutes or does not at all and just gets frozen at it. (the number keeps going up, and `efibootmgr` displays tons of entries).

The second issue is, when I press shutdown, it shuts down and after 4 seconds starts back up again. Actual restart also restarts but does not wait 4 seconds before starting back up again.

(I should mention that I also have a PC, with Asus Z170i Pro Gaming motherboard, running Kubuntu 19.04 and I am not facing this issue on it.)

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,7152b409-422f-4ba9-8019-0d4d778b4210,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

EDIT: Sometimes "restart"-ing actually shuts it down.

Comment: have you reported it at lanchpad? this sounds like a bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: nah, i didn't. i just want this to work.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v` ? Append it to your question.

Comment: alright i did that

Comment: Possible bug and workaround at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1835639

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly your issue, but I ran into the same error when I installed Mint for dual-booting with Windows. My HP laptop had the option in UEFI > Boot options > Advanced to add a Customized Boot. It allows you to enter a path and that's where I added `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. Then I changed the boot order to have Customized Boot on top and it booted into Grub magically. Woohoo.

Mainly posting this for anyone who may come across this in the future.